# Check if a value exists in a json file with python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I've the following json file (banneds.json):

```
{
  "players": [
    {
      "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/07/07aa315f664efa92456569429230bc2c254c3ff8_full.jpg",
      "created": 1595050663,
      "created_by": "<@128152620136267776>",
      "nick": "teste",
      "steam64": 76561198046619692
    },
    {
      "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/21/21fa5c468597e9c890212b2e3bdb0fac781c040c_full.jpg",
      "created": 1595056420,
      "created_by": "<@128152620136267776>",
      "nick": "ingridão",
      "steam64": 76561199058918551
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to insert new values if the new value (inserted by user) is not already in the json, however when I try to search if the value is already there I receive a false value, an example of what I'm doing ( not the original code, only an example ):

```py
import json

check = 76561198046619692
with open('banneds.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
if check in data:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

I'm always receiving the "False" result, but the value is there, someone can give me a light of what I'm doing wrong please? I tried the entire night to find a solution, but no one works :(

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking data as a dictionary object. When checking using `if check in data` it checks if data object have a key matching the value of the `check` variable (`data.keys()` to list all keys).

One easy way would be to use `if check in data["players"].__str__()` which will convert value to a string and search for the match.

If you want to make sure that `check` value only checks for the `steam64` values, you can write a simple function that will iterate over all "players" and will check their "steam64" values. Another solution would be to make list of "steam64" values for faster and easier checking.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I followed your idea and created a list and append all steam64 values to this list, after that I used 'in' to verificate. All works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any()` to check if value of `steam64` key is there.

For example:

```
import json


def check_value(data, val):
    return any(player['steam64']==val for player in data['players'])

with open('banneds.json', 'r') as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

print(check_value(data, 76561198046619692))
```

Prints:

```
True
```